# JavaScript - Get the Date of the next Day of the Week (For each day)

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

I have made an online calendar, and I would like to add the date next to the day of the week. For example, it would say `Monday (6/18)`. My current code works fairly well but gets the day of the current week starting from Monday. This means that since today is Wednesday, it displays the date of two days ago, instead of *next* Monday, which is the intended effect.

Current Code:

```
var today = new Date();
var mon = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay()+1);
var tue = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay()+2);
var wed = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay()+3);
var thu = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay()+4);
var fri = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay()+5);
var sat = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay()+6);
var sun = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay()+7);

$(".mon").html("Monday (" + (mon.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + mon.getDate() + ")");
$(".tue").html("Tuesday (" + (tue.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + tue.getDate() + ")");
$(".wed").html("Wednesday (" + (wed.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + wed.getDate() + ")");
$(".thu").html("Thursday (" + (thu.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + thu.getDate() + ")");
$(".fri").html("Friday (" + (fri.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + fri.getDate() + ")");
$(".sat").html("Saturday (" + (sat.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + sat.getDate() + ")");
$(".sun").html("Sunday (" + (sun.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + sun.getDate() + ")");
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

From today to next 6 days.

```js
var arr = [];
var today = new Date();
for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
var date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()+i);
  arr[date.getDay()] = date;
}

$(".mon").html("Monday (" + (arr[1].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[1].getDate() + ")");
$(".tue").html("Tuesday (" + (arr[2].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[2].getDate() + ")");
$(".wed").html("Wednesday (" + (arr[3].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[3].getDate() + ")");
$(".thu").html("Thursday (" + (arr[4].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[4].getDate() + ")");
$(".fri").html("Friday (" + (arr[5].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[5].getDate() + ")");
$(".sat").html("Saturday (" + (arr[6].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[6].getDate() + ")");
$(".sun").html("Sunday (" + (arr[0].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[0].getDate() + ")");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="mon"></span><br/>
<span class="tue"></span><br/>
<span class="wed"></span><br/>
<span class="thu"></span><br/>
<span class="fri"></span><br/>
<span class="sat"></span><br/>
<span class="sun"></span><br/>
```

Here is another example with function getNextDay to get the given Date's next day of the week:

```js
var arr = [];
var today = new Date();
for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
  arr[i] = getNextDay(today, i);
}

function getNextDay(date, day){
  var difference = day - date.getDay();
  if(difference < 0)
    difference += 7;
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + difference);
}

$(".mon").html("Monday (" + (arr[1].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[1].getDate() + ")");
$(".tue").html("Tuesday (" + (arr[2].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[2].getDate() + ")");
$(".wed").html("Wednesday (" + (arr[3].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[3].getDate() + ")");
$(".thu").html("Thursday (" + (arr[4].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[4].getDate() + ")");
$(".fri").html("Friday (" + (arr[5].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[5].getDate() + ")");
$(".sat").html("Saturday (" + (arr[6].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[6].getDate() + ")");
$(".sun").html("Sunday (" + (arr[0].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + arr[0].getDate() + ")");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="mon"></span><br/>
<span class="tue"></span><br/>
<span class="wed"></span><br/>
<span class="thu"></span><br/>
<span class="fri"></span><br/>
<span class="sat"></span><br/>
<span class="sun"></span><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see next week's values why not increment all by extra 7, ie

```js
var mon = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay()+8);
```

Comment: This way, the date of tomorrow would be in 8 days instead of one. I want next week only if the day has passed.